# What is the 'checkout complete' URL for a bigcartel store?

Tags: url, google-analytics, checkout, bigcartel, goal-tracking

I am trying to set up a google analytics goal for my site. I want to monitor the number of completed checkouts, however without purchasing a product (there are a number of reasons why I am unable to do this), I am unable to find out what the URL would be.

Example: www.myshop.bigcartel.com/CheckoutComplete.html

I would like to know the actual value for '/CheckoutComplete.html'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Analytics is enabled in the Big Cartel admin, a page view event is sent for the `/order` URL. The full URL is different for every order, but if you setup your goal as just `/order` you should be good to go.